# C# converting 1 x 3 matrix to a 3 x 3 matrix with Special conditions

Tags: c#, matrix, nested-loops

I have this code to read a `1x3 matrix (1 5 9)` from a text file and make a `3x3 matrix` out of it.

The output matrix should be:

`1 0 0`

`0 5 0`

`0 0 9`

***using a loop*** (and conditions - *if needed*). The closest I got is:

`1 0 0`

`5 0 0`

`9 0 0`.

Here's my code:

```
    for (int x = 0; x <= 2; x++)
    {
          for (int y = 0; y <= 2; y++)
        {
            sw.Write("{0} ", matrix[x, y]);
            sw.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    sw.WriteLine();
    sw.Close();
```

Comment: I'm trying to manipulate it with the loops. Or is it not possible?

Comment: It is homework - so answer is in the question: it said "and conditions" - so you need to see where to use condition... Maybe you can explain what condition is true for position of non-zero number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I think you can do it.
Let's consider matrixA the original matrix and matrixB the final matrix.

Here is the logic

```
//Convert 1x3 into 3x3
for (int x = 0; x <= 2; x++)
{         
        matrixB[x,x]=matrixA[x];
}
//Display Matrix 
for (int x = 0; x <= 2; x++)
{
      for (int y = 0; y <= 2; y++)
    {
        sw.Write("{0} ", matrix[x, y]);
        sw.WriteLine();
    }
}
sw.WriteLine();
sw.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Linq. Make sure you add System.Linq to your using clause. I did see that you want to use loops. I'll leave this here anyway for reference as a more idiomatic way of expressing the solution.

```
  var matrix1 = new int[] {1,5,9};
  var matrix3 = matrix1.Select ((v, i) => {
    var n = new int[matrix1.Length];
    n [i] = v;
    return n;
  });
  foreach (var v in matrix3)
    Console.WriteLine ("{0} {1} {2}", v[0],v[1],v[2]);
```